# Reload jframe connected to database

Tags: java, database, jframe

i have built graphical user interface in java connected to sql server data base where the user can insert and read data from sql server through this interface . Is there a method to reload and refresh this interface after a user sent query to sql server and update data into database without close the frame and re-open ?

Comment: Yes, you write it - what that might look like would depend on how you're displaying and managing your data

Comment: Regarding your first question, yes, there is:  [fireTableDataChanged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged%28%29).  Since you have not shared your code, I am assuming that you have written a subclass of AbstractTableModel to hold your data items.